# What is the meaning of "one carries with one out"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Favourite (2018)*, Anne is up to her neck in a large pool of bubbling mud which leach out her toxins. Abigail sits next to her. Sarah enters and says to Abigail:

> Sarah: After you left, I thought, "What a grand idea to take to the
>   mud." To get whatever poisons **one carries with one out**.

What is the meaning of "one carries with one out"?

Answer (score 1):

Here [*one*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one#Pronoun) is used as a pronoun. It's  The verb is "*to get [smth] out*", and the object is "*whatever poisons one carries with one*".

Sentences with *one* can be confusing, maybe it's clearer with he/him:

> whatever poisons **he** carries with **him**

Comment: Does it simply mean **extract poison from the body**?

Answer (score 0):

It means the same thing as the more natural sounding:

> To *get* ***out*** whatever poisons one carries (with one).

It's unusual to put *out* at the end of the sentence—normally it's part of the verbal phrase *get out*. Sometimes, you can insert a single word in the middle of the phrase (*get **it** out* or *get **something** out*), but rarely are the two words separated so much as in the sentence in the question.